# Parsing XML with JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file which I am trying to parse ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
    <post>
        <heading>Test Post, Please Ignore</heading>
    </post>
</root>
```

And the JQuery I'm using alongside it ...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"postList.xml",
            dataType:"xml",
            success:function(xml) {
                $(xml).find("post").each(function() {
                    var pTitle = $(this).find("heading").text();

                    $("#output").append("<p>" + pTitle + "</p>");
                });
            },error: function() {
                alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Every time I preview my site in broswer it throws an error (the one written into the JQuery). I have tried it in IE, Firefox and Chrome and have used W3C's XML Validator to make sure that that is all in check and yet it still doesn't work. 
From what I can tell it *should* work and yet it doesn't. Instead it throws the error every time and my page is left with an empty `<div id="output">`. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** I moved the XML file to the same folder as the html file and updated the url so that it has the correct address. It now appears to work in Firefox, but still throws and error in IE and Chrome ...

Comment: change the error handler to `error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
    }

` and see the actual error that is thrown

Comment: Thanks, the error it throws in Chrome is `error::` and `error:Error:Access is denied. :undefined` in IE
I moved the XML file to the same folder as the page and it now works on Firefox, but nothing else ...

Comment: are you loading the page from a `file:` path? or do you have a web server from which you are serving the web page using `http/s:` protocol

Comment: whether the error is gone now?

Comment: I am currently testing it straight from my hard drive, so all files are local

Comment: @ArunPJohny Error is still there, but only on Chrome and IE

Comment: Then it is because of same origin policy violations.... whether both the files are in the same folder? can you load the file from a web server that will be much more easier to work with

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have hosted the XML document here - http://puu.sh/71GFP.xml and updated the document to read `url:"http://puu.sh/71GFP.xml",`
It is now throwing the error `error::` on Chrome and Firefox, but IE works

Comment: no still it will result in same origin policy violation

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't quite understand what you are saying ... Do you mean that even thought I have the file hosted it will still cause the same error? If so, it is now throwing a different error and working in one browser, but not the other two (one of which, it was previously working in). 
Also, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: the same origin policy(in ajax) prevents the browser from making ajax calls to any other domain than from which the main page was loaded... so if your html is hosted in hard drive(`file://` protocol) and the xml is in a remote location then it will not allow you to access the xml using ajax

Comment: @ArunPJohny I see. Would that mean that if both files were hosted locally it should work? And also, it is currently working, but only in IE when the html is local and the XML is hosted elsewhere ... Shouldn't that not be working?

Comment: yes but all browser implement those restrictions differently

Comment: @ArunPJohny What would you recommend as a solution to this then?

Comment: for testing use http://plnkr.co/edit/gm5JARgGhi0E3Is8wJzW?p=preview

Comment: what is your actual requirement? where will be the file hosted and where will the xml be hosted? will be hosted in different domains

Comment: @ArunPJohny Once the site is complete it will all be hosted on a single server of the same domain. Does this mean that this problem will be solved once the website is hosted through a hosting service?

Comment: yes... if that is the case I would recommend you host a local web server for the development purposes... else it will always be a headache.... is it a static website or a dynamic one.... do you have any server side scripting

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have managed to host it locally and it's working great, no server-side scripting currently, seem to be doing just fine with HTML5 and JQuery. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll post the suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out It was a problem with Same Origin Policy violation where the files was loaded from the local hard drive(file:// protocol).

Since the project is supposed to be deployed in a web server, the suggested fix is to use a local web server to host the files so that the same origin policy violations can be rectified.